# Dashboard in webpart - asks all users if they wanna activate

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I have a webpart, showing a Diagram, from a excel workbook in our SharePoint(online)

The diagram reads a table from another workbook(also in our sharepoint) and it's set to update all connections every 15 mins. But everytime someone refreshes that page in sharepoint, they are being asked if they wanna active that "maybe unsafe connection" - is there a way to stop that message, and just show them the webpart?